# How to get a Date object from String

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");
Date d = (Date)formatter.parse(dateTime);
System.out.println("date in controller "+d);
```

I get the output as

> date in controller Mon Dec 31 16:04:57 IST 2012

Please suggest a method to output the date in `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` format.
Need the output in date format and not as string so as to store the output in `datetime` field in mysql db

Comment: need to store in db as datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Need the output in date format and not as string so as to store the output in datetime field in mysql db
```

After the statement

```
Date d = (Date)formatter.parse(dateTime);
java.sql.Date sqldate = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime())
```

you have got a `java.util.Date` object and **you can store it as it is in mysql DB** (column type : datetime).

However, when you are printing `d`, it defaults to the `.toString()` implementation. I think you expected some output like Date@ but the toString printed in user readable format thats why the confusion.

Comment: I think it is necessary to convert the the `java.util.Date` object `d` into `java.sql.Date` object: `java.sql.Date sqldate = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());` and then put it into the database.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `d` an object of `Date` class, so its `toString` method is called that gives the output as `Mon Dec 31 16:04:57 IST 2012`.

If you want to display it in the format that you have specified in your `SimpleDateFormat` then try using this :

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");
Date d = (Date)formatter.parse(dateTime);
System.out.println("date in controller "+ formatter.format(d));
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't see why the single-qoutes (') are used in the format-string and you also need to catch `ParseException`:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date d = new Date();
try {
    d = (Date)formatter.parse("12/31/2012 12:13:14");
} catch(ParseException pex) { System.out.println(pex.getMessage()); }
// convert the date into java.sql.Date
java.sql.Date sqldate = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());
// then put it in the database, something like this:
//resultSet.updateDate("myDateTimeField", sqldate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println("date in controller"+ df.format(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using format instead of parse.

```
Date date = new Date();
String DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy";      
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);        
System.out.println("Today is " + sdf.format(date) );
```